# What is webhookId and deployKeyId when mirroring a bitbucket repository in google cloud

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, webhooks

We have a lot of bitbucket repositories which I am trying to link to google cloud so I can use automatic build triggers to build container images.

If you set up a build trigger using a bitbucket source through the admin panel interface, google seems to create a mirrored source repository, adds a ssh key on bitbucket (so it can pull any changes) and also add a bb service (old style webhooks) on the repository so that pushing to bb triggers a pull in to google (i.e. mirroring).  This all seems to work well, but **I would like to be able to set this up programatically via an API.**

I can setup the bitbucket stuff fine using their API but I am not sure how to go about creating the google repository using [this](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/create)

Using the API to fetch an existing mirrored repository gives some clues about how it works.  The **mirrorConfig** key is the key.

```
{
"name": "projects/my_project_id/repos/bitbucket-organisation-myrepo",
"size": "7670706",
"url": "https://source.developers.google.com/p/my_project_id/r/bitbucket-organisation-myrepo",
"mirrorConfig": {
 "url": "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/organisation/myrepo.git",
 "webhookId": "12299619",
 "deployKeyId": "6759258"
 }
}
```

The POST service setup in bitbucket is:

```
https://source.developers.google.com/webhook/bitbucket?id=M12A8PQNCVD&project=385688625156
```

Notice how the ids in google don't correspond with the bitbucket webhook url.  Adding another repository gives completely different ids and creates a new ssh keypair on my bitbucket user every time.

**webhookId** looks like it's linking to some sort of "google cloud webhook" which must be how the bitbucket webhook is linked up with the google webhook, but I cant see where you find or create them.

**deployKeyId** sounds like it's linking to some sort of credentials store which must be where it stores the private key.

My question is, what are these two IDs really? and which APIs can I use to setup webhooks and deploy keys in google cloud?